# How do I add space at the end of page results when using append?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am trying to add space between results when i am using the append function. 
I am using export delimiter which i am appending the data and adding SKIP at the end of my export statement.

how can achieve this?

Thank you.

I have tried using double spaces, using ","

```
 export delimiter ","
    col1
    col2
    col3
skip.

Im expecting output similiar as shown below.

Results
Space
Results
Space
Results
Space
Results
Space.

Thank you
```

Comment: I am confused.  Where is there any use of APPEND?  And what is the relevance of "page results" when your code seems to be focused on individual lines and a space (blank line maybe?) between them?  I see accepted answers but they seem, to me, to be answering a very different question.  Namely "How do I add one or more blank lines after data written with EXPORT?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple skips will not work in an export action. You can use PUT UNFORMATTED though...

```
OUTPUT TO value("c:\tmp\jp1.txt"). 
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DO i = 1 TO 10:
    PUT UNFORMATTED "JP" "," "PV" "," "HX" SKIP(1).  
END. 
OUTPUT CLOSE. 
MESSAGE 1
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try multiple skips. Like skip(1) or skip(2). If it still doesn't work, try putting a put skip statement after your export command.